# CASCADE DELETE how to delete child rows

Tags: mysql, innodb, cascade

I have 3 tables

`player`, `goal`, `card`

how should i build my database so it automatically deletes `goal` and `card` row containing `player id`?

my declarations of tables i suppose i should add on delete cascade but i don't understand it very well so can any of you help me?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__footsal_players` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`ordering` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`state` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`checked_out` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`checked_out_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_team` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`first_name` varchar(255)  NOT NULL ,
`last_name` varchar(255)  NOT NULL ,
`birth_date` DATE  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`email` varchar(255)  NOT NULL ,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__footsal_goals` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`state` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`checked_out` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`checked_out_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_player` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_resault` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`goals_number` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL ,
`id_session` VARCHAR(11)  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__footsal_yellow_cards` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`state` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`checked_out` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`checked_out_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_player` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`id_resault` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Comment: I didn't, i prefer fk to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MySQL running atm, but code below should work for goals. The idea is that when you define the foreign key, you assign delete and update rules. These apply when the primary key (id in player) is modified. So when the primary key in player is deleted (i.e. the player is deleted), the rows with corresponding foreign keys, behave according to their rule. Cascade means 'follow', so in this case delete it too.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__footsal_goals` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`state` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`checked_out` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`checked_out_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_player` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_resault` INT(11)  NOT NULL ,
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`goals_number` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL ,
`id_session` VARCHAR(11)  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY goals_player_fk (`id_player`) 
REFERENCES `#__footsal_players` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Comment: `goals_player_fk` name for it is strict or i can replace it with any?? because i tryied to inplement `card` but got error 150

Comment: you can use any name you like, but the names have to be unique within the database. So for card I suggest you use card_player_fk. I prefer to give meaningful names, whenever a foreign key integrity rule is violated, a dbms will typically throw an error with this name, so a meaningful name helps to find where something went wrong.